# Elasticsearch Date Histogram Aggregation over a Nested Array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river, spring-data-elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

Following are a couple of sample documents in my elasticsearch index:

```
{
  message: "M1",
  date: "date object",
  comments: [
    {
     "msg" :"good"
     date:"date_obj1"
   },
   {
    "msg" :"bad"
     date:"date_obj2"
   },
   {
    "msg" :"ugly"
     date:"date_obj3"
   }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  message: "M2",
  date: "date_object5",
  comments: [
    {
     "msg" :"ugly"
     date:"date_obj7"
    },
    {
     "msg" :"pagli"
     date:"date_obj8"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to find number of documents per day and number of comments per day.
I can get the number of documents per day by using the date histogram and it gives me the correct results. I make the following aggregation query

```
aggs : {
    "posts_over_days" : {
        "date_histogram" : { "field" : "date", "interval": "day" }
         }
    }
```

But when I try similar thing to get comments per day, it returns incorrect data, (for 1500+ comments it will only return 160 odd comments). I am making the following query:

```
aggs : {
    "comments_over_days" : {
        "date_histogram" : { "field" : "comments.date", "interval": "day" }
         }
    }
```

I want to know how to get the desired result? Is there a way in elasticsearch to get what I want?
Please let me know if I need to provide any other info.

Expected Output:

```
buckets: [
 {
   time_interval: date_objectA,
   doc_count: x
 },
  {
   time_interval: date_objectB,
   doc_count: y
 }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Value Count](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) aggregation - this will count the number of terms for the field in your document.  E.g. based on your data (5 comments in 2 documents):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mydata/_search?search_type=count&pretty' -d '{
>    "aggs" : {
>         "grades_count" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "comments.date" } }
>     }
> }'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
   },
   "aggregations" : {
    "grades_count" : {
     "value" : 5
    }
  }
}
```

### Adding the Date Buckets

the Value Count aggregation can be nested inside the date buckets:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mydata/_search?search_type=count&pretty' -d '{
  aggs : {
   "posts_over_days" : {
     "date_histogram" : { "field" : "date", "interval": "day" },
     "aggs" : {
         "grades_count" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "comments.date" } }
       }
     }
  }
}'
```

with results:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "posts_over_days" : {
     "buckets" : [ {
        "key_as_string" : "2014-11-27T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1417046400000,
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "grades_count" : {
          "value" : 2
        }
      }, {
        "key_as_string" : "2014-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1417132800000,
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "grades_count" : {
          "value" : 3
        }
      }
```